# How to add recurring to all product by default monthly?

Tags: ubercart

I am using ubercart and uc_recurring module and Drupal6.  I wanted to add monthly payments to all products by default.  How can i do this ?

I added a rule to add the data to the DB  using php code while creating new product

```
$data = array(
  'pfid' => ' ',
  'nid' => $node->nid,
  'fid' => 'recurring',
  'description'=>'When this product is purchased, add a fee for the same amount as the product selling price charged first after 0 days and every 1 months after that 99 times.',
);
drupal_write_record('uc_product_features', $data);

$q = "SELECT pfid FROM {uc_product_features} WHERE fid= '%s' AND nid = %d";
$result = db_query($q, 'recurring', $node->nid);
$num = db_result($result);


$data2 = array(
  'pfid' => $num,
  'model' => ' pro',
  'fee_amount' => ' ',
  'initial_charge'=>'0 days',
 'regular_interval'=>'1 months',
  'number_intervals'=>100,
);
drupal_write_record('uc_recurring_product', $data2);
```

Still recurring is not working? When i go to the path /node/*/edit/features and simply submit the form without updating any fields it works?

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its solved by changing the code in rules

```
<?php
    //Recurring
    $data = array(
   'pfid' => ' ',
   'nid' => $node->nid,
   'fid' => 'recurring',
   'description'=>'When this product is purchased, add a fee for the same amount as the product selling price charged first after 0 days and every 1 months after that 99 times.',
     );
   drupal_write_record('uc_product_features', $data);

   $q = "SELECT pfid FROM {uc_product_features} WHERE fid= '%s' AND nid = %d";
   $result = db_query($q, 'recurring', $node->nid);
   $num = db_result($result);


  // Build the recurring fee's product object.
   $product->pfid = $num; //pfid
   $product->model = '';
   $product->fee_amount = 0.000;
   $product->initial_charge = '0 days';
   $product->regular_interval = '1 months';
   // If number intervals is negative, it means that it's unlimited intervals.
   $product->number_intervals = 100;
   $product->nid = $node->nid;

   uc_recurring_product_feature_save($product);
 ?>
```

I am not sure whether its a proper way..